# If $f$,$g$ and $\overline{f}g$ are holomorphic on $\Omega$, then $g=0$ or $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $\Omega$ is an open connected subset of $\mathbb C$, $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on $\Omega$ and $\overline{f}g$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, then $g=0$ or $f$ is constant.

If $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and $g(x+iy)=u'(x,y)+iv'(x,y)$, we have $$u_x=v_y \space ; u_y=-v_x,$$ $$u'_x=v'_y \space ; u'_y=-v'_x$$

The product $\overline{f}g$ is $$\overline{f}g=(u-iv)(u'+iv')$$ $$=uu'+vv'+i(uv'-vu')$$

By hypothesis, $\overline{f}g$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, so by the Cauchy-Riemann equations we obtain

$$(1)\space  u_xu'+uu'_x+v_xv'+vv'_x=u_yv'+uv'_y-(v_yu'+vu'_y),$$ $$(2) \space u_yu'+uu'_y+v_yv'+vv'_y=-(u_xv'+uv'_x)+v_xu'+vu'_x$$

Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $f$ and $g$, we have

$(1)$ reduces to $(1)' \space v_yu'=v'u_y$

$(2)$ reduces to $(2)' \space u_xv'=v_xu'$

I don't know how to arrive to the conclusion $g=0$ or $f$ is constant from here. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It's much easier and cleaner if you use the Wirtinger derivatives, for example. Have you already learned about the Wirtinger derivatives?

Comment: Hint: Suppose $g \neq 0$. Then there is an open set $U \subseteq \Omega$ where $g$ never vanishes. Try to show that $f$ is constant in $U$ using the open mapping theorem. Then $f$ must be constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've read about those operators in Stein's textbook but it didn't occurred to me to use them. Specifically, are you suggesting to use the fact that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$ for all $z \in \Omega$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}$? (where $f=u+iv$)

Comment: By assumption, $\frac{\partial (\overline{f}g)}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$. Also, $g$ is holomorphic, so $\frac{\partial g}{\partial\overline{z}} = 0$. Thus, by the product rule, and the interplay of the Wirtinger derivatives with conjugation, you get $\overline{f'}\cdot g = 0$. Does that make it easier?

Comment: @DanielFischer Of course it does, from there it is immediate. Thanks!

Comment: @Crostul I'd like to try your approach, but I don't know what to do. If $f$ is not constant, then for any open subset $S \subset U$, $f(S)$ must be open, I don't know how to prove this isn't the case.

Comment: $1/g$ is holomorphic, hence $\bar{f} = \bar{f} g / g$. But then $f+ \bar{f}$ is an holomorphic function with values in $\mathbb{R}$, whose interior is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of comments. The Wirtinger derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$ are efficient tools for such computations. Being first-order differential operators with constant coefficients, they obey the usual rules of differentiations like the product and chain rules. Being holomorphic means having $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}=0$. So, 
$$
0 =  \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} (\bar f g) = \frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial \bar z}  g = \overline{f'}g 
$$
For nonconstant holomorphic or antiholomorphic functions, the zeros are isolated. Thus, if the product of two such things is identically zero, one of them is identically zero. Conclusion follows.

Comment: I was trying to show that as the zeros of the two functions are isolated, then one of them is identically zero but I couldn't, could you give me some ideas to prove it or a a sketch of a proof ?

Comment: @user156441 Take a point $a$ where one of functions is zero. There is $r>0$ such that this function is *not* zero when $0<|z-a|<r$. So, for all these $z$ the *other* function must be zero, but it can't be.